# Facebook: Retrieve actions of an app

Tags: facebook, action

The iHeartradio facebook app posts actions on my timeline saying

Syed thumbed up Pee loon on iHeartRadio.

Can I fetch these actions posted by iheartradio through facebook graph api in MY application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You just need to request specific permission for user actions from that app's namespace.

1. Find a story from your or a friend's timeline activity log for that app
2. Get the URL to the object being acted on
3. Use the OG Debugger to scrape the OG metadata for that object
4. Get the `fb:app_id` value and go to [graph.facebook.com/APPID](http://graph.facebook.com/APPID) using this value as APPID
5. Get the `namespace` value from the JSON array returned
6. Ask for user_actions:namespace and friends_actions:namespace for the namespace value above
7. Fetch actions for a user with graph.facebook.com/USERID/namespace:action for the given namespace and action name

Easy, right?